# How many reputation do you need in order to be able to vote to reopen or close a question?

Tags: support, reputation, vote-to-close, re-open

How many reputation do you need in order to be able to vote to reopen or close a question??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's 3000. See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

If you have at least 15 points then you can flag the post for close/reopen review.